# Raising and Case Marking

Tags: theoretical-linguistics

Can someone explain subject-to-subject raising and case marking from a syntactic point of view? How/where do the NPS get Case-marked?

Thank you

Comment: does this https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/42990/a-fundamental-question-about-subject-to-subject-raising answer your question?